# ¿Hay alguna forma de borrar el IDLE de python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una pequeña utilidad con una interfaz a base de menús predefinidos seleccionables con input, en el IDLE, y me gustaría que después de cada selección se borrara la pantalla del **IDLE** y dejara el 'lienzo' en blanco. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

**Lo que YA he probado y no funciona:**

.- Esto borra una ventana CDM, no el IDLE

```
import os
os.system ("cls")
```

.- Esto no hace nada:

`Ctrl + L` (He probado diferentes teclas, sin efecto alguno)

Comment: No hay manera de borrar el texto de IDLE, ya que como has comprobado no es una consola de tu OS. Lo que puedes hacer es el viejo truco de imprimir un montón de líneas en blanco! Por ejemplo `print ("\n" * 100)`

Comment: Gracias, pero no me parece una solución 'elegante'. He leído por algún sitio que había un parche de los developers del IDLE para poder hacerlo, ya que, al final, es una interfaz diseñada con tkinter para python. Seguiré buscando...

Comment: Supongo que siempre podrías probar con los códigos ansi: `print(“\033[H\033[J”) `, básicamente sitúas el cursor en el primer espacio (`[H`) y borras todo a partir de ahí (`[J`). No tengo ni idea de si funcionará en IDLE, pero si lo hace en muchas otras consolas. Hay varias preguntas/respuestas mencionándolo en SO (especialmente en inglés), como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55672752/14083367) donde lo explica bastante bien. Si eso no te funciona, buena suerte buscando la funcionalidad que indicas, porque no he encontrado nada en la doc de IDLE. Aunque admito que no he buscado demasiado..

Comment: En idle, lo veo posible, pero dificil. Internamente idle usa tkinter... Si pudiera encontrar la forma de acceder al widget Text y borrar su contenido... Sin embargo, te doy la noticia de que si abres tu programa con doble clic, os.system("cls") funcionará bien!

Comment: No, ninguna de estas dos cosas funciona en IDLE. Sí en la consola del sistema operativo, pero no es lo que necesito (ni lo que se especifica en la pregunta). Por otro lado, haciendo doble click en el script, se abre el archivo en el IDLE pero no se ejecuta automáticamente, hay que pulsar F5, por lo que os.system('cls') tampoco funciona así.

Comment: Pensé que tenias asociado el doble clic con el interprete de Python. En realidad mi comentario era que iba a funcionar en una consola DOS.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las ideas. Encontré una forma de hacerlo que funciona de maravilla. Lo pongo en respuestas:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No ha sido fácil conseguirlo, pero el resultado es totalmente satisfactorio. Aquí les dejo una solución que ha funcionado para mí:

**Previo:**
La demanda de algunos usuarios de poder borrar el shell del IDLE de python viene de hace tiempo, y los developers no se acaban de poner de acuerdo en la forma de implementarlo, aunque se hizo un 'issue' oficial (https://bugs.python.org/issue6143) que acabó en un patch que se puede implementar manualmente.

**Modificando el Shell:**
El archivo se puede descargar del enlace anterior (*ClearWindow.py*), y debe ser colocado en la carpeta de instalación de python, dentro de `\lib\idlelib`. Además, hay que añadir las siguientes líneas en el archivo '`config-extensions.def`' que se encuentra en la misma carpeta:

```
[ClearWindow]
enable=1
enable_editor=0
enable_shell=1
[ClearWindow_cfgBindings]
clear-window=<Control-Key-l>
```

Esto, añade una nueva opción en el IDLE Shell, dentro del menú 'Opciones', que se llama 'Clear Shell Window', y que se puede ejecutar mediante la combinación de teclas '`Ctrl + L`'

**Añadiendo algo de código:**
Finalmente, para que el resultado sea precisamente el buscado, había que emular la pulsación de teclas '`Ctrl + L`' mediante código, algo que yo he hecho con estas líneas:

```
import win32api, win32con
def cls():
    win32api.keybd_event(13,0,0,0)  # enter
    win32api.keybd_event(13,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)  # Release the button
    #  Press down Ctrl+L
    win32api.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(0x4c, 0, 0, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(0x4c, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    win32api.keybd_event(0x11, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Así, solo tengo que llamar a `cls()` cuando necesite borrar el Shell.

**Resultado:**
Efectívamente, esto borra todo el texto del IDLE Shell, sin posibilidad de recuperar lo borrado, aunque nos sirve perfectamente para lo que se requería, que era poder hacer un menú de 'inputs' seleccionando opciones, y borrando toda la salida previa.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, crea una nueva opción dentro del menú de IDLE, pero para poderlo usar desde el código, se debe primero hacer lo siguiente:

1. Instalar el paquete win32:
   •   Abrir una ventana CMD con permisos de Administrador.
   •   Ir a la ruta de instalación de Python, en mi caso C:\Program Files\Python310 y ahí ejecutar el comando python -m pip install pywin32
2. En la misma ruta de instalación de Python, ejecutar el comando python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install. Dentro de los mensajes, saldrán los nombres de los archivos .dll que hay que copiar
3. Ir a la ruta C:\Windows\System32 y copiar los archivos pythoncom310.dll y pywintypes310.dll.
4. Pegar los archivos anteriormente copiados a la ruta Python instalación\Lib\site-packages\win32, en mi caso es C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages\win32.
5. Cerrar y volver a abrir el IDLE.
6. Ejecutar su programa e incluir en la parte del código que se necesite, la función anteriormente definida cls().

Excelente ayuda